# I want to refresh list programmatically using Swift

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

```
struct MealView: View {
    @State var meals: [String] = []
    ...
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
...
                List(meals, id: \.self) { meal in
                        Text(meal)
                }
                .refreshable {
                                sendGetRequest()
                            }
            }
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        print("refreshed")
        self.sendGetRequest()
    }
    
    func sendGetRequest() {
        meals = ["급식을 가져오고 있어요."]
        let schoolCode: ...

        let url = URL(string: "https://open.neis.go.kr/...")!
...
meals = [...]
        }
        // 7. 요청 실행
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

```
...
@main
struct mealtimeApp: App {
    @State private var selection = 1
    @AppStorage("_isFirstLaunching") var isFirstLaunch: Bool = true
    @State private var settingsPresented = false
//    @State private var isFirstLaunch = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ...
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isFirstLaunch) {
                    ...
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $settingsPresented) {
                    ...
                    }
                        .onDisappear {
                            MealView().refresh()
                            print("dd")
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

These are my code.
I'm calling `MealView().refresh()` just after the sheet closes.
And in `MealView().refresh()`, it calls `sendGetRequest()` to refresh the list's data using the updated `schoolCode` and `officeCode`. So, it sends request and gets the data.
However, the list is not updated and it still displays the old data.

I want to update the list and display the fetched new data.

Comment: Your code in the mealtimeApp is strange, where do you create and show the view? And doing MealView().refresh() in onDisappear doesn’t make sense. The MealView itself looks correct but I think you also should call sendGetRequest in onAppear

Comment: Every time you call “MealView()“ you create a different instance, one does not know about the other. Try some basic tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a text field that updates a counter by using ZStack and .hidden() in your list will force refresh. There might be a better way and if so I’d love to know!

```
struct MealView: View {
    @State var meals: [String] = []
    //...
    @State var refreshing:Int = 0 // <- force refresh
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                //...
                List(meals, id: \.self) { meal in
                    ZStack {
                        Text(String(describing: Int(refreshing))).hidden() // <- force refresh
                        Text(meal)
                    }
                }
                .refreshable {
                    sendGetRequest()
                }
            }
        }
        
        func refresh() {
            print("refreshed")
            self.sendGetRequest()
        }
        
        func sendGetRequest() {
            meals = ["급식을 가져오고 있어요."]
            //let schoolCode: ...
            
            //let url = URL(string: "https://open.neis.go.kr/...")!
            //...
            //meals = […]

            // Force refresh
            refreshing += 1
            // Limit refreshing size
            if refreshing > 9 {
                refreshing = 0
            }
        }
        // 7. 요청 실행
        task.resume()
    }
}
```